# How to catch all user interactions on the app

Tags: android

How to catch all user interactions on the app?
I've been trying `activity.onUserInteraction` but it doesn't catch interactions with **dialogs** or even **EditText** interactions.

Do I need to manage individually in each editText and dialog?

Comment: Interactions mean? Are you asking for whenever user touches the `sensor` or in terms of `EditText` inputs?

Comment: I want to know when user is using the app, therefore any view interaction (including dialogs, editTexts, clicking in view areas, buttons etc) @MustansarSaeed

Comment: If `Activity` is in `onResume` state then consider it that user is using the application, if in `onPause` then user is not using.

Comment: This is not accurate. Activity passes through onResume state during a while. But the user can be inactive in the app anytime

Answer (score 0):

In the activity, any touch/gesture will pass through `dispatchTouchEvent`. you can override it

```
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
         Log.d("MyActivity", " dispatchTouchEvent: ");
         if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
           // do something
        }
        else if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
          // do something else       
        }
// ... so on
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. However that doesn't cover when you are writing inside an EditText

Comment: I'm might need dispatchTouchEvent from window, instead from activity